# iterating over a queryset and replacing foreign keys with their related objects django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, iteration, django-queryset, prefetch

I have the following models:

```
class STUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...

class VenuePermissions(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(STUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    ...

class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1500, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

I am then prefetching the related `venuepermission` objects to a `STUser` object in a view

```
class VenueUserList(APIView):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  objects = STUser.objects.prefetch_related('venuepermissions_set').all()
   ...
```

Then I want to take the returned query set and replace the `venue` FKs with their objects.

```
 for item in objects:
        for permission in item_venuepermissions_set:
            permission_venue = Venue.objects.get(pk=permission_venue)
    print(repr(objects))
    ...
    return Response({})
```

but my approach is clearly wrong. how do I properly access a field of a queryset and change its value?

As you can see I need to do it twice. Once to access the current objects permission_set and again to access that permission_set venue field and override it.

I do not want any of this changing the database. This is just to return the values.

update:

I made the following changes to get access to the individual fields:

```
for item in objects:
            for permission in item.venuepermissions_set:
                permission.venue = Venue.objects.get(pk=permission.venue)
        print(repr(objects))
        return Response({})
```

the new error I have is:

```
TypeError: 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable
```

trying to resolve

Answer (score 2):

Answering all my questions today:

```
class VenueUserList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        objects = STUser.objects.prefetch_related('venuepermissions_set').all()
        for item in objects:
            for permission in item.venuepermissions_set.all():
                permission.venue = Venue.objects.get(pk=permission.venue_id)
        return Response({})
```

is the way to do it